# Power BI: Data Refresh on SQL Server on Microsoft Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, azure-virtual-machine

In the desktop version of Power BI, there is data that is from a SQL Server stored on an Azure Virtual Machine. The data has no problems manually connecting and refreshing in the desktop application, but this data is not being refreshed automatically. Gateway is installed on the same Virtual Machine that the SQL Server is on. DirectQuery is used in Power BI to connect to the SQL Server.

Comment: This question seems too broad. In order to get useful help, consider adding specific and relevant information about your setup.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there could be a couple of issues here. I've listed them below in bullet form.

1. Ensure scheduled refresh is enabled through the PowerBi online
   service.
2. Ensure the firewall isn't blocking the gateway on the SQL server.
3. Ensure the credentials you are using with the gateway have read
   permission to the database.

Even when the gateway is installed and working correctly. Live refresh isn't a feature that is available within the desktop client. This can only be achieved by clicking the "Refresh" button on the desktop client. Other than that I don't think I can provide any further help without additional information.